# AWS CloudWatch Alarm using @message filtering inside log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

Does anyone knows how to create an alarm in CloudWatch using @message filtering inside log groups? Tried in Metrics with no option of filtering log groups as metrics.

Comment: Did you try [Creating Metrics From Log Events Using Filters - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes i tried creating a metric filter via log groups but log groups is not showing on the filter and when I try creating a dashboard it shows the log groups I needed for the log events

Comment: @JohnRotenstein was able to see it trying it now. is it also okay to change the source of the metrics example ("<Log groups>", "<filtered message>" as by default it should be under log groups or adding the filter on the source will make it easier for the alarm to trigger?